# How to pass a regular expression as an argument to a function?

Tags: ruby, regex, watir

The following line of code correctly selects "Joe Bloggs" from a dropdown:

```
browser.select_list(:id => "ListOwnerID").option(:text => /Joe Bloggs/).select # edited: added '.select'
```

How do I pass the owner's name as the variable "list_owner"?

Something like:

```
def set_list_owner(list_owner)
    browser.select_list(:id => "ListOwnerID").option(:text => /list_owner/).select
end
```

Usage:

```
set_list_owner("Joe Bloggs")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Regexp::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-new):

```
re_string = '\d'
Regexp.new(re_string) =~ 'abc 123'
# => 4
```

Alternative Cary Swoveland suggested (regular expression interpolation):

```
/#{re_string}/
```

---

```
def set_list_owner(list_owner)
    browser.select_list(:id => "ListOwnerID").option(:text => Regexp.new(list_owner))
end

set_list_owner("Joe Bloggs")
```

---

If you want to match the string literally, instead of interpreting as a regular expression, use [`Regexp::escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape):

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(list_owner))
```

Comment: Alternatively, `regex = /#{re_string}/ => /\d/`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Nice solution. I added your alternative to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I used `Regexp.new(list_owner)`. At least, I can understand that :)